# Fetch content from (WordPress) api in sapper

Tags: json, wordpress, svelte, sapper

I am working with the sapper start template https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper-template and confused on how to approach fetching data from an external API (in this case WordPress).

I have modified /blog/_posts.js this contained `const = posts = [...all the json..]` - first I tried replacing this with `const = posts = fetch('http://localhost:9000/wp-json/wp/v2/posts');`  which gives an error fetch is not defined - so I included node-fetch - which now returns an error in server `js posts.map is not a function`

I have been reading to try and find an answer and tried things like:

```js
let posts;
export async function preload(page, session) {
    posts = await this.fetch('http://localhost:9000/wp-json/wp/v2/posts');
    return { posts }; 
}
export default posts;
```

from `_posts.js` which results in:

```js
const contents = JSON.stringify(posts$1.map(post => { 
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Unfortunately I cannot find any documentation or examples how to do this - so reaching out as I try to learn sapper, advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The result of calling `this.fetch` (or `fetch`) is a `Response` object, *not* the data. You need to do something like this:

```js
export async function preload(page, session) {
  const r = await this.fetch('http://localhost:9000/wp-json/wp/v2/posts');
  return {
    posts: await r.json()
  };
}
```

Don't define `posts` outside the function body or `export default` from the `<script>`.

Comment: Just re-read the question — I see you're trying to fetch this data inside a server route. `preload` is for use in *components*, not .js files. In a server route you would need to fetch the data inside your `get` handler (using `node-fetch`, plain `http`, or any one of the gazillion request libraries on npm): https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper-template/blob/master/src/routes/blog/index.json.js

Comment: I was looking for your answer using with component. I'm not sure how to build such a component yet. There is no example in https://svelte.dev/tutorial IIRC

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer Rich.

I spent some time trying the above and being a little confused where it belonged (_posts.js erroring without exporting default, and figured it was intended there), before reading your comment :) 

It sounds like I need something along the lines of 
    ```const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const posts = fetch('http://localhost:9000/wp-json/wp/v2/posts').then(function(r) {
 return r.json();
});

export default posts;```

within _posts.js  however this results in `TypeError: posts.map is not a function` - perhaps because code lacks await ?

Comment: Yes, at the moment `posts` is a Promise in your code